# Autonomous Partitioning of Table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

Is it possible to make Autonomous Partitioning of a table in Oracle ?

I want the new partition get created automatically on exceeding the range or limit assign to it. Suppose I partitioned a table on the basis of year and I want as soon as the new year begin the new partition must be created automatically, means I don't have to create it manually.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the Oracle version you're using.  You've tagged this for both 10g and 11g and the answer is different between the two.

In 11g, you can use [interval partitioning](http://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/partitioning-enhancements-11gr1.php#interval_partitioning) to have Oracle automatically create new partitions when new data is inserted.  Prior to that, you'd need to explicitly create the partitions you need.  You could always, of course, allow new rows to be inserted into one partition with a very large `MAXVALUE` and then split the partition later on but I assume that's not exactly what you're looking for.

If you're partitioning on a date, you could also create a scheduled job that created partitions just before they are needed.  If you really wanted to, you could also create hundreds of partitions in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your response ,here i needs to create a system in which partition get created automatically in case if i leave the organization no body has to bother about it or needs to look after it. I tagged it oracle 10g and 11g as i am looking for solution in both the cases .

Comment: @DharmeshPorwal - You could create a scheduled job that periodically created new partitions.  If you leave the organization, though, presumably someone else will be maintaining the application.  Creating new partitions is a relatively simple maintenance process so I'm not sure why you'd be concerned about that rather than the myriad of other application support tasks that whoever replaced you would need to take care of.